# Generic way to Parse Spark DataFrame to JSON Object/Array Using Spray JSON

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, spray-json

I'm trying to find a generic way**(without using a concrete case class in Scala)** to parse Spark DataFrame to JSON Object/Array using Spray JSON or any other library.

I have tried to approach this using spray-json and my current code looks something like this

```
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

val list = sc.parallelize(List(("a1","b1","c1","d1"),("a2","b2","c2","d2"))).toDF

list.show
+---+---+---+---+                                                               
| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1| d1|
| a2| b2| c2| d2|
+---+---+---+---+

val json = list.toJSON.collect.toJson.prettyPrint

println(json)
```

Current Output:

```
["{\"_1\":\"a1\",\"_2\":\"b1\",\"_3\":\"c1\",\"_4\":\"d1\"}", "{\"_1\":\"a2\",\"_2\":\"b2\",\"_3\":\"c2\",\"_4\":\"d2\"}"]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    "_1": "a1",
    "_2": "b1",
    "_3": "c1",
    "_4": "d1"
}, {
    "_1": "a2",
    "_2": "b2",
    "_3": "c2",
    "_4": "d2"
}]
```

Kindly suggest how to get the expected output in the required format without using a "concrete scala case class". Either using spray-json or any other library.

Comment: Your current implementation is List of a tuple.
Maybe you created it for example.

In your final implementation are you going to have List[List[String]] or it's going to be like this List[(String, String, String, String)] -> which your example is using. 

Because the format will make a difference in implementation

Comment: Yes, I have created this as an example. In the final implementation, DF.collect will return something like this "Array([a1,b1,c1,d1], [a2,b2,c2,d2])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various approach using various libraries, I finally settled with the below simple approach.

```
val list = sc.parallelize(List(("a1","b1","c1","d1"),("a2","b2","c2","d2"))).toDF

val jsonArray = list.toJSON.collect
/*jsonArray: Array[String] = Array({"_1":"a1","_2":"b1","_3":"c1","_4":"d1"}, {"_1":"a2","_2":"b2","_3":"c2","_4":"d2"})*/

val finalOutput = jsonArray.mkString("[", ",", "]")

/*finalOutput: String = [{"_1":"a2","_2":"b2","_3":"c2","_4":"d2"},{"_1":"a1","_2":"b1","_3":"c1","_4":"d1"}]*/
```

In this approach, we no need to use spray-JSON or any other library.

Special thanks to @Aman Sehgal. His answer helped me to come up with this optimal solution.

Note: I'm yet to analyze the performance of this approach using a large DF but with some basic performance testing it looks equally fast to ".toJson.prettyPrint" of "spray-json".

Answer (score 2):

I took help from an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388624/format-json-string-in-scala?answertab=active#tab-top). If you would have had a look here, I think you would have got your answer.

You're correct half way through. By adding custom formatting code, you should be able to get your output in desired format.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray   
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONFormat   
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject   
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONType

// Thanks to Senia for providing this in her solution
def format(t: Any, i: Int = 0): String = t match {
  case o: JSONObject =>
    o.obj.map{ case (k, v) =>
      "  "*(i+1) + JSONFormat.defaultFormatter(k) + ": " + format(v, i+1)
    }.mkString("{\n", ",\n", "\n" + "  "*i + "}")

  case a: JSONArray =>
    a.list.map{
      e => "  "*(i+1) + format(e, i+1)
    }.mkString("[\n", ",\n", "\n" + "  "*i + "]")

  case _ => JSONFormat defaultFormatter t
}

val list = sc.parallelize(List(("a1","b1","c1","d1"),("a2","b2","c2","d2"))).toDF

// Create array
val jsonArray = list.toJSON.collect()

val jsonFormattedArray = jsonArray.map(j => format(JSON.parseRaw(j).get))

res1: Array[String] =
Array({
  "_1": "a1",
  "_2": "b1",
  "_3": "c1",
  "_4": "d1"
}, {
  "_1": "a2",
  "_2": "b2",
  "_3": "c2",
  "_4": "d2"
})
```

Convert formatted Json to string

```
scala> jsonFormattedArray.toList.mkString(",")

res2: String =
{
  "_1": "a1",
  "_2": "b1",
  "_3": "c1",
  "_4": "d1"
},{
  "_1": "a2",
  "_2": "b2",
  "_3": "c2",
  "_4": "d2"
}
```

Comment: The performance of .toList.mkString(",") is very bad. Should try some optimized approach if posible.

Comment: Finally jsonArray.mkString("[", ",", "]") did the trick. Thanks for your detail answer.